# how to port pentaho data integeration kettle plugins to apache hop?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

In the [document](https://hop.apache.org/dev-manual/latest/porting-kettle-plugins.html), I see change maven dependency but I cannot find the correct maven dependency for the hop, I mean they have mentioned `Change group pentaho-kettle to org.hop`
but I couldn't find any dependency for `org.hop`.

Can anyone say what exactly I need to do, or what exactly they are referring to?

can I use `org.apache.hop` is that the same??

Answer (score 1):

Good catch, we'll update the documentation.

`org.apache.hop` is correct.

Hop doesn't publish artifacts to maven central (yet).
You can either build Hop locally or add the Apache repository to your pom:

```
    <repository>
      <id>Apache</id>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
      <name>Apache Repository</name>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Thanks Bart Maertens, but still i'm getting error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hop-engine: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hop:hop-engine:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.hop:hop-core:jar:tests:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT in Apache (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/) `  can you take a look.

Comment: you'll need to work in a separate repository, changing code in the original kettle repository won't work. The examples in this repository could be helpful:  https://github.com/project-hop/hop-plugins